# Have each element in list contain each other element

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I have a model similar to this:

```
public class Model
{
    public Model(string first, string second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }

    public string First { get; }
    public string Second { get; }
}
```

And a list similar to:

```
var options = new List<Model>
{
    new Model("op1", "A"),
    new Model("op1", "B"),
    new Model("op1", "C"),
    new Model("op2", "X"),
    new Model("op2", "Y")
};
```

And I'd like to get a list of all the different options there can be found in the list if we take the First property as key. I was thinking a `List<List<Model>>` would suffice here. With the options given, the result would have to be:

```
{ {"op1", "A"}, {"op2", "X"} }
{ {"op1", "A"}, {"op2", "Y"} }
{ {"op1", "B"}, {"op2", "X"} }
{ {"op1", "B"}, {"op2", "Y"} }
{ {"op1", "C"}, {"op2", "X"} }
{ {"op1", "C"}, {"op2", "Y"} }
```

Keeping in mind the source list can have N different groups (more elements where First is "op3"). How do I go about solving this? Im having trouble writing a recursive method for this though it seems like it is the perfect fit.

Comment: Does your model only have the two values First and Second? If so, take a look at Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53165519/1753173. The extension method generates a list of lists of any type while Devanshi Mishra's answer works for strings only (using the + operator).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```cs
class ListBuilder
{
    Dictionary<int, List<string>> options = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    public ListBuilder()
    {
        options.Add(1, new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" });
        options.Add(2, new List<string>() { "X", "Y"});
        //you can initialize multiple lists here
    }

    public List<string> AllCombos
    {
        get  { return GetAllPossibleCombos(options); }
    }

    List<string> GetAllPossibleCombos(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>> remainingOptions)
    {
        if (remainingOptions.Count() == 1)
        {
            return remainingOptions.First().Value;
        }
        else
        {
            var current = remainingOptions.First();

            List<string> outputs = new List<string>();
            List<string> combos = 
                GetAllPossibleCombos(remainingOptions.Where(option => option.Key != option.Key));

            foreach (var tagPart in current.Value)
            {
                foreach (var combo in combos)
                {
                   outputs.Add(tagPart + combo);
                }
            }

            return outputs;
        }
    }
}
```